# Neo4j determing the neighbours

Tags: neo4j, traversal

I am very new in Neo4J concepts. 
I would like to know how, if there is any way, to list all the possible nodes connected to a particular node after it has been deployed in the graphdb format.
To put it simply, I have been **able to import a tab seperated .csv** 
And now I would like to know if it is possible to list all the neighbours of any particular node, whose id can be passed as parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways. One of them is to use a Cypher statement like below:

```
START n=node({nodeId}) MATCH n-[*1..1]-m RETURN m;
```

If you're using Java, you could use the traversal API as follows:

```
for (final Path position : Traversal.description()
    .evaluator(Evaluators.fromDepth(1))                     
    .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(1))
    .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition()).traverse(yourStartNode)) {
        System.out.println(position.endNode());
}
```

Comment: there's no need to use `n-[*1..1]-m`. simply use `n--m`.

Answer (score 0):

i would add to the tstorms answer a collection, so you will get all nodes+ collection of neigbours in one row:

```
START n=node({nodeId}) MATCH n--m RETURN n,collect(m);
```

or for all nodes and their neighbours:

```
 START n=node(*) MATCH n--m RETURN n,collect(m) order by Id(n);
```